# Find the remainder when $3^{103}$ is divided by $53$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I used Fermat's little theorem to obtain $3^{104} \equiv 1\pmod{53}$ but how do I get $3^{103}$? The answer is $18$.

Comment: Well...$3^{103}\times 3 \equiv 1 \pmod {53}$.  Have you learned about modular inverse yet?  Do you know how to solve $3x \equiv 1 \pmod {53}$?

Answer (score 2):

$$3^{103}=3^{-1}\cdot(3^{52})^2\equiv3^{-1}\cdot1^2\pmod{53}$$

Now use $$3\cdot18\equiv1\pmod{53}\implies3^{-1}\equiv?$$

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to find inverses?

If $3^{103}\equiv a \pmod {53}$then

$3^{104} \equiv 3a \pmod {53}$ and by FLT $3^{104}\equiv (3^{52})^2 \equiv 1^2\equiv 1 \pmod {53}$.

so $3a \equiv 1 \pmod{53}$.  So you need to find the value $3^{-1}$ where $3^{-1}\cdot 3 \equiv 1 \pmod{53}$.

As $53 + 1 =54$ is divisible by $3$ this is pretty easy to find just be guessing.  $3\cdot 18 = 54 \equiv 1\pmod {53}$ so $3^{-1}= 18\pmod {53}$ and $a\equiv 18\pmod {53}$.

The verify (if you want to):

$3a \equiv 1 \pmod {53}$ so

$18\cdot 3a \equiv 18\cdot 1 \pmod {53}$ so

$a \equiv 18 \pmod {53}$.

Answer (score 0):

$3^{-1}\equiv18\bmod{53}$, because $-1\cdot53+3\cdot18=1$.